# Exoplayer play HLS m3u8 video which encrypt by AES - 128

Tags: android, encryption, aes, exoplayer

I got the URL m3u8 which encrypted by AES - 128
example :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:13
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="INfeStYsHgLdHXY4HgO0SQTdSdbfGQC4HXHeStaqGNKnGdVdHtOtGXZfGtS3H2O4SNOtGNG2GXffGNYsINerGdUsHdHgGtS4TgY5Hda0S2C1TdO4GQGrSdDfHNHcHXw1TXCsSNGqIK==.key",IV=0x30633461363563636238376531316333
#EXTINF:10.416667,
https://DOMAIN/HdKtHXGrHdKtIXStHdKtING4HdStGXGqHdCtGdGqGtKnTdwtHtPdHteqTXVcS2PcIXC1HAY4HgO4GdwqTNY2IAO1HAGqTNwqSNe5HXTgGdG1S2HfINO0G2PfGdVgTXTgGNfdHXVfHNU0GXC2HAK3GdG0GNS2TgC4SNPfTgOrTNYrSgK5G2Y4GAS4TNVgGtHeTXfdS2ZdH2TgSQSqHdHfSQG0G2ZgHXHdGtPbGdGrINesTgSrGNVcS2LbIXUqS2C4INxbTAK2Gtw3HXCqTQG3GXbdINHeHtOrSK==.ts
....
```

from this m3u8 file, I can get key, IV param. I think chuck .ts URL was encrypted also.
However, I have no idea about AES - 128 encryption.

Could you guys please help me to play this file by Exoplayer on an Android device?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ExoPlayer has built in support for encryption in DASH and HLS streams.

The encryption and key information can be signalled in multiple places, typically in the manifest (M3U8 or mod files) and in 'blocks' or 'Atoms' in the media streams themselves.

Depending on how your encryption is set up the key will either be included in the manifest (obviously not very secure), available in the clear from a key server (still not very secure) or served via one of the usual DRM key serveing mechanisms, Widevine, PlayReady or FairPlay (as secure as the DRM schemes are at any given time).

You should not have to do anything extra on the ExoPlayer side to make this work, unless your video server requires the key to be locally provisioned.

If you are seeing some particular error during playback it may be worth asking a question on that specifically and if possible sharing the full manifest, stream and error logs.

Comment: Thank sir for comment, I tried play m3u8 file by Exoplayer, The Exoplayer can not play file and show the log cat about source error (404). I also tried request HTTP to .ts file and get 404 not found. so I think my url .ts was encrypted. 
What I got is Key , IV , list of ts URL.

Can you help me to play this file

Comment: @DươngNguyễnVăn if you can share a link to the video that would help understand the problem.

Comment: Can I chat with you by email or whatsapp, sir?